# Login Instagram with Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, automation, bots, selenium-firefoxdriver

I'm trying to login to my personnal page with python. But each time I try to login, it looks working but after redirect me to an other login page. I don't understand why? The username and the password dispay good and the login button is turning but always Instagram redirect me to an other Login

```
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

# Configuration des options pour Firefox
options = Options()
options.set_preference("network.cookie.cookieBehavior", 2)  # Accepter automatiquement les cookies

# Initialisation du navigateur
browser = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)

# Naviguer vers Instagram
browser.get('https://www.instagram.com/')

# Attendre que la page charge
sleep(5)

# Accepter les cookies si la fenêtre apparaît
try:
    cookie_accept_button = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[text()='Accept All Cookies']")  # Sélecteur XPath du bouton de consentement des cookies
    cookie_accept_button.click()
except NoSuchElementException:
    pass  # Ignorer si le bouton de consentement des cookies n'est pas trouvé

# Continuer le processus de connexion
try:
    login_link = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[contains(@href, '/accounts/login/')]")  # Rechercher le lien de connexion par le chemin d'accès de l'URL
    login_link.click()
except NoSuchElementException:
    print("Le lien de connexion n'a pas été trouvé.")

sleep(2)

username_input = browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='username']")
password_input = browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='password']")

username_input.send_keys("myusername")
password_input.send_keys("mypassword")

login_button = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@type='submit']")
login_button.click()

# Attendre que la connexion soit terminée
sleep(5)



# Fermer le navigateur
#browser.close()
```

Comment: It would probably be easier to use [playwright](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/intro), it is a much newer library than selenium, and allows running firefox, msedge, chrome, webkit, and chromium, _without a webdriver_.

Comment: I will look, thanks, I'll keep you in touch!! Thanks